# UIScrollView as a subview does not scroll

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

When I set my **UIScrollView** to be the main view within Interface Builder, the scrolling works as expected. However, when I add the **UIScrollView** as a subview of **UIView** the scroll does not work.

So it seems my trouble begins when the **UIScrollView** is added as a subview to **UIView**.

The "**User Interaction Enabled**" it true for both view.

I though perhaps I might have to do something with in **touchesBegan** something lake passing the touches to the **UIScrollView**, but have not had much luck with that.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you post some code ? Such as how you initialize the UIScrollView...

Comment: What is the `contentSize` of your scroll view?

Comment: Did u get the answer.? i am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to show a complete working code snippet:

```
// in viewDidLoad: 

//UIScrollview *myScrollView;

UIView_descendent *contentView;
// scrollview won't scroll unless content size explicitly set

[myScrollView setContentSize:contentView.frame.size];
```

I have not found a way to set contentSize in IB.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.delegate = scrollView;  //or nil may work
```